# Is historical costuming / clothing on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, tags

The clothes people wore in times before ours -- the materials and methods they would have used, the techniques, the sourcing even! -- is a rich part of history that Wikipedia can't cover well.

Are questions about such topics welcome here?

Comment: http://history.stackexchange.com/q/1415/961

Comment: ...and http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/2371/what-is-the-history-of-the-popped-collar , or anything else under the tag [tag:fashion]. 6 Questions with an average upvote total of just less than 6. That's a damn high score for a question on this stack.

Comment: I asked a clothing-related question 5 months ago and it has not been closed (so far?) http://history.stackexchange.com/q/1712

Answer (score 7):

It's not that far off-topic, we tend to cover a wide range here.  We have had some uniform questions already so you would have company, but so long as there is a historical basis to the question the community is rather lenient and the question may elicit some good answers.

Answer (score 7):

That stuff is about as on-topic as it gets. Silk, cotton, flax, and wool have been major forces in shaping World history. For example, see my answer to [Why did the United Kingdom industrialize first?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/2146/why-did-the-united-kingdom-industrialize-first) and the accepted answer to [When and how did the USA and the UK become allies?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/1579/when-and-how-did-the-usa-and-the-uk-become-allies)